# Magento 2 : How can i get all category with all eav attributes in collection?

Tags: magento2, category, collection, category-attribute

How can I get all categories with all EAV attributes in the collection?

```
$categories = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection');
$categories->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

> $categories->getData(); give me the following data

[image]

I want all available EAV attributes in this collection

Comment: Try this $categories->getData('attribute_code')

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code so that it will give all details in array:

```
$categories = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection');
$categories->addAttributeToSelect('*');
echo "<pre>";
print_r($categories->toArray());
```